# problems with sorting the cases and controls in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

I am using weighted majority voting in machine learning. Will it create the problem if I train the data using all control data first followed by all case data? case = 1,control = 0 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]

Answer (score 0):

If you are feeding your data in batches, for example in NN, then it is a big problem, and gradients used for SGD are not good estimates for the gradient of the full batch. Thus in that case you should randomize your data.

For RF and SVM etc the ordering does not matter, since the calculations are always performed on the full data.